# Cannot read property '' of undefined using javascript

Tags: javascript

My page gives the below data when I run the command `digitalInfo;` in console log.

```
> digitalInfo;
< >{version: "1.0", page: {...}, attributes: {...},event: Array(0), ...}
```

If I expand this response and go to to `"page"` key, I get below date for page key:

```
>page:
>pageInfo: {pageName: "Thank You", language:"en"}
>productInfo: [{}]
>user: {loginStatus: "Not LoggedIn", userType: "Anonymous"}
```

If I expand the `productInfo` I get the following date for `productInfo` key:

```
productInfo: Array(1)
0
flightTime: "Flight-1 06:50~Flight-1 08:35"
```

Now I want to fetch the value of flightTime so I am using below command (command first) :

```
var departureInfo=digitalInfo.page.productInfo[0].flightTime;
```

But that gave me the error @productInfo[0] as `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I modified the command and made it as (command second) :

```
var departureInfo=digitalInfo.page.productInfo.flightTime;
```

But this time it gave me error as : `Cannot read property of 'flightTime' undefined`

these commands when I include in my `javascript` throws me the error. However if I run the first command on console directly, I get the output as :

```
>var departureInfo=digitalInfo.page.productInfo[0].flightTime;
>departureInfo;
<"Flight-1 06:50~Flight-1 08:35"
```

Code:

```
<script>

(function()
{
     'use strict';
      var cnt=6000;
      function init() 
      {
          if(typeof jQuery !="undefined")
          {         
            content_change();   
          }
          else
          {
              cnt=cnt-500;
              if(cnt>500)setTimeout(init,500);
          }
      }


function content_change()
{
  console.log("entered the content change function");

var departureInfo=digitalInfo.page.productInfo[0].flightTime;


    if(checking value of departureInfo)
    {       
console.log("Entered the if loop");
    }
    else
    {
       cnt=cnt-500;
          if(cnt>500)setTimeout(content_change,500);
    }   
 }
 init();
})()
</script>
```

Comment: You need to post the actual code involved.

Comment: `productInfo` is undefined, probably some kind of sync issue. You need to post the codes

Comment: Hi @Huangism , digitalInfo is the datalayer (javascript object) and I want to retrieve the value of flightTime.

Comment: You need to show how `digitalInfo` gets its data. If the data is present at alltimes, you would not have this problem so I am guessing you get it from the server and the issue you are experiencing is due to you trying to access the data before the server call returns it

Comment: Hi @Huangism , yeah my doubt is the same. How could I check if server has returned the data and then I retrieve the value ?

Comment: Post the code you are using to get the data, there should be a complete function, inside of it you shall have your data completely

Comment: Hi @Huangism I have posted the javascript logic in the question body.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari unfortunately your code does not include how `digitalInfo` gets its data

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this via setTimeout function. Thank you everyone for the suggestions.